# Show Validation Message on submit in Angular 4 Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 4, Reactive forms.I want to show validation error message when the user clicks on Submit/Create Account button. 
Here is the HTML and typescript code that I am using.

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" 
           id="firstname" 
           name="firstname" 
           formControlName="firstname" 
           placeholder="First Name">
    <span *ngIf="!signupForm.get('firstname').valid && signupForm.get('firstname').touched" 
           class="help-block"> Please Enter First Name (Minimum 2 Characters)</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" 
           id="lastname" 
           name="lastname" 
           formControlName="lastname" 
           placeholder="Last Name">
    <span *ngIf="!signupForm.get('lastname').valid && signupForm.get('lastname').touched" 
           class="help-block"> Please Enter Last Name (Minimum 2 Characters)</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" 
            class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-qte">Create Account</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

---

TYPE SCRIPT CODE

---

```
export class UserRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
    signupForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
            'firstname': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
            'lastname': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2),]),
            'businessname': new FormControl(null),
            'phonenumber': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
            'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
            'password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
            'confirmpassword': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)

        });
    }

    onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.signupForm)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.signupForm)
    this.signupForm.controls['firstname'].markAsTouched()
}
```

Answer (score 19):

you can do this using from `markAllAsTouched()` method.
it will mark all the form controls as touched and by doing so will trigger validation errors where needed

```
onSubmit() {
    this.signupForm.markAllAsTouched();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the properties like `touched`, `dirty`, `valid` of form control through `formGroup` use :

`signupForm.controls.firstname.touched`. same way you can get the other properties like valid and invalid.

if you have created individual object of `FormControl` then, you can access that object properties as `firstname.touched` without using `formGroup`.

for more information about the validation in Model Driven Forms refer [Model Driven Form Validations](https://www.ngdevelop.tech/angular/tutorial/form-validators/) here.