# Angular 4 required field validation not working on click of save form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I am implementing basic required field validations in my angular 4 reactive form and seem to have trouble getting it to work.  Could somebody tell me where i am going wrong

In my implementation the validation triggers and the input field gets highlighted only when i set focus on the form control. I want it to trigger when I directly press the save button.

First Implementation

```
  <form [formGroup]="newMovieForm"  (ngSubmit)="save(newMovieForm.value)">
      <div class ="col-sm-12"> 
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
           <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!newMovieForm.controls['title'].valid && newMovieForm.controls['title'].touched}">
              <label for="movie-title" class="control-label">Title of Movie</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="movie-title" placeholder="Title of Movie" formControlName="title" maxlength="100">
           </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
          <button type="submit" class="button" >Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

**newmovie.component.ts**

```
  initializeFormModel()
  {
    this.newMovieForm = this._fb.group({
       title: ['',[Validators.required]]
     });
  }


    save(model:IMovie){
            this._movieService.createMovie(model).then((result:any)=>{
            this.newMovieId = result;
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774192/show-validation-message-on-submit-in-angular-4-reactive-forms

Answer (score 1):

I think it will trigger when you hit the save button. However remember all your validation is doing at the moment is highlighting the input field. What you are missing at the moment is something stopping you saving an invalid movie.

You either need a check that disables your Save button while the form is invalid or something in your Save function that checks whether the form is valid and doesn't save the movie if it is invalid.

Comment: I did have that check of  forms.valid state in the save method but however though that check worked , my form field wouldn't get highlighted when the user clicked the save button .  I think it's got to do with forms touched property . The touched property state would only change when you focus on that control but not when the save button is clicked . I may be wrong but that's what I think

Comment: Yes good point. The simplest way I can think of to get round that is to add a saveClicked boolean to your component that you set to true in the save method and add that into your has-error check.

Comment: So does that mean I remove to touched property check

Comment: No because you want that if user clicks on the text box and then clicks on another part of the page. I was thinking of something like:

[ngClass]="{'has-error':!newMovieForm.controls['title'].valid && (saveClicked || newMovieForm.controls['title'].touched)}"

Comment: Not sure why I am getting parsing error on this div element <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!newMovieForm.controls['title'].vali‌​d && (isValid || newMovieForm.controls['title'].touched)}">

Comment: Looks like i am missing some parrenthesis